JS/TS How to Reuse Code Between Projects?
Maybe there is an approach that I don't know.
I spent a while and tried various methods such as js/ts with npm link, git submodules, tsconfig paths, symlink, npm/pnpm/yaml workspace, npm pack & npm link, package.json exports, package.json commonjs/module, and nx(nrwl)/lerna. Each approach has disadvantages, and it looks like there are no convenient standards.
Problem:
As a developer,
I want to write code and reuse it.
I want to start a second project and use only the code I need.
I have code, and I need to share it between multiple projects with the ability to update it.
I am looking for clear instructions.
I use JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA as my IDE.
I don't want to mess or overcomplicate the code with package management, configs, commands, or other techniques that slow down development and introduce too many extra steps.
I can't use a monorepo because there are tens of projects, and the IDE doesn't perform well with searching, replacing, etc.
The code looks like:
/unit_domain_project_1
. .git
. package.json
. /src
. . /units # library
. . . /meter.ts # module 
. . . /meter.test.ts # unit testing
. . /nodejs
. . . # Node.js code in TS not compilable in browser
. . /browser
. . . # Browser code in TS not compilable in nodejs

/furniture_project_2
. .git
. package.json
. /src
. . table.ts # here I want to reuse only 'units'

/building_project_3 # extra nesting example 
. /src
. . house.ts # here I want to reuse only 'table' with 'units/meter'

Workaround:
The best solution I found is to use symlink like ln -s $ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_PROJECT_1/units, but for Docker, it requires extra shell scripting.
Question:
How can I reuse units?
(Please answer with step-by-step instructions.)
Why These Approaches Are Not Ideal:
(Described below have cross problems)

git submodules - Requires git pull/push in each project.
symlink - requires shell scripting copy ./linked_code_source ./linked_code with Docker.
tsconfig paths - Does not support relative paths out of parent(base), IDE not resolve deps.
package.json exports: {'*./'} - There is a mess with package.json commonjs/module, I have to compile TypeScript into module JavaScript. I meet problems with dependencies and path resolving. Many hours just to make it work.
npm link - Not working with Docker, requires shell scripting.
npm/pnpm/yarn workspace - Depends on the npm/node version, makes or symlink or copy file, not updating, need a post_install scripting, rebuilding packages.
npm pack & npm link - need updating script.
nx(nrwl)/lerna - In general, I have to follow their folder structure and use build commands, which means I have to split code into libraries and provide configurations and package.jsons, introducing complexity that shouldn't be there.


"I can't use a monorepo because there are tens of projects, and the IDE doesn't perform well with searching, replacing, etc." Some monorepos have hundreds of packages. Like, that's what they are for; sharing code between different applications.

The general solution is really to publish an npm package, and install that in each project using the shared code. It's pretty simple although publishing updates does add friction, and private packages are not free.

If there is a development guide in/linked from the readme that may have dev environment setup included. If not, you could try opening an issue on the repo with a request to include this info in the docs and cite what you've tried that hasn't worked to get setup so far.

What you are describing is really a "monorepo" definition, I'm not sure why you're trying to get away from it, that's the approach used by large enterprise projects like Angular. My favorite approach for monorepo nowadays is to go with pnpm workspace: protocol, TypeScript project references and Lerna-Lite for the versioning/publishing of all the npm packages. I use pnpm to run the command in targeted package(s), but you could also use TurboRepo or Nx to speed up runs by using caching.

Monorepos, usually projects contain multiple applications. For example, Unity (which has its own version control system) or Flutter, but both of them might use JavaScript code. A monorepo is great when the tech stack is consistent. In the case of a multi-stack setup, it can be cognitively complex. I prefer to have a small repository per application. At the same time, I am looking for a solution that doesn't involve creating packages, or if it does, it should be extremely easy, like in one command.

Packages, In my experience, it's more like:

Create code
Refactor it, make sure it is atomic
Move to a package
Set up isolated package configuration, like tsconfig, jest, package.json
Introduce some global path resolving, 'tsconfig.path:@company/project_library'
Set up isolated compilation (for commonjs, module, es5, esnext)
6.1 Resolve all dependenices or set up webpack or another bundler
Build into node_modules
Run watcher and rebuilders
Now you have to do it for another 50+ libs or don't do it atomic and deploy everything in one library (:


npm link based workflows are a nightmare !
I would definitely go to a Monorepo structure using a tool like turborepo (lerna, nx are alternatives too). You need to invest a bit of time but then it works like a breeze comparing to other solutions
Publishing a shared library on npm/yarn also works but you have to pay if you want it to be private. Managing the different versions is a huge hassle too.

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review
